# Task Scheduler on Windows 10 not working anymore

Tags: python, windows, process, task, scheduler

I have made a Python Script which scrapes some data out of a website, using the Mozzila driver. At the end of the script, it saves the data into an Excel and then closes the browser with browser.quit(). After fixing all the bugs and issues I could find, using pyinstaller I have crated an executable. The final task was to run this executable everyhour, everyday... so I used Task Scheduler.

These are the settings of the task:

[image]

[image]

[image]

For aprox. 3 months, while using Windows 7, the script run non-stop with NO issues. It didn't matter if the user was logged in or not, if the computer was sleeping, or if the screen was turned off. Three days ago, my company forced me to install Windows 10, and since then, the script doesn't run anymore. I will try to explaing its behavior:

Using the same settings for the task in Task Scheduler, at hour X it starts and it finishes and all the cmd script/Firefox/geckodriver process` are closed. It runs for the next 3-4 hours, but the next hour it crashes. The cmd script/firefox/geckodriver process' do not close (the data is not saved) and it remains stuck! I have to manually end the tasks, so it can run the following hour. Manually starting the script from Task Scheduler works too (but ofc, if the past process' of the script are closed)

I tried selecting stop the task if it runs for more than 5 minutes (the script finishes its work in less than 2 minutes), it doesn't work. I've tried creating a .bat file that opens the .exe, and assign it to the task instead of the .exe. Same result...

Since the update to Windows10, I can not make it work for 1 day straight. I do not know what to do anymore... This script is supposed to run everyday, everyhour (like it did when I was using Windows 7)... but I cannot wake up in the middle of the night to check it, manually close the process' and so on.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried changing `Configure For` to `Windows 10` in that first window?

Comment: Yes, tried that too. Same result.

Comment: It's hard to diagnose with only the information at hand. But I would try handling the hourly jobs from within the Python exe. This way you run it once from Task Scheduler and have Python handle the processes

Comment: And how would I do that?

Comment: It really depends on your script but essentially you would be running the functions and then sleeping for 60 minutes with `time.sleep(3600)` before running again. This would all be in something like a `while True:` loop

Comment: What you are saying is this: run the script always, but only do "something" every 3600 seconds.

Comment: Correct. I try to avoid delegating much work to Task Scheduler. You can also check out the [schedule](https://github.com/dbader/schedule) module if you want to get more complicated

Comment: Do you know if it works whether the user is logged in or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207310/discussion-between-matt-m-and-chiser-alexandru).